# How to instantiate polygon array in java

Tags: java, arrays, instantiation

I ***thought*** that

```
 Polygon[] polygon = new Polygon[3];
```

would work. It runs through the 'new' line completly fine, but once it hits adding a point, it does a null pointer exeption. I add a point like so (NPEs here)-

```
polygon[0].addPoint(256, 417);
```

However, doing it like below works, but I do not want to have a potentially large number of 'new Polygon()'. Is there a way to do it like my first line of code?

```
Polygon[] polygon = { new Polygon(), new Polygon(), new Polygon() };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do something like this:

```
Polygon[] polygons = new Polygon[3];
for (int i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++)
{
    polygons[i] = new Polygon();
}
```

The first line *just* creates an array - and an array is always filled with null references (or zero values etc). No `Polygon` objects have been created at this point, which is why you try to use `polygons[0].addPoint` you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

If you want to populate it with references to newly created *objects*, you need to explicitly create those objects.

Comment: ah, thank you. I saw in debug mode that when I used new polygon[3] each polygon was null, and when I used new Polygon() they were not. Thank you for clearing that up! (learning code through google = hard + not learn everything)

Comment: @khyperia: Yes, that's really not a great way of getting started - I recommend that you get an introductory book. You'll save *huge* amounts of time that way.

Comment: Yeah... but Ive been coding for a year now, and my dad is a pretty good programmer. Its just little things like this that I don't know. Thanks, though! I may just go over some big online tutorials instead of a book, though...

Answer (score 0):

There are good tutorials on the Oracle Java site. Read them. They don't go into a lot of depth but they're a good start. There are also good articles around the Web for which it's really true that Google is your friend (GIYF). Search for "Java tutorial", "Java introduction" or something along those lines.